# How do I resolve Free Fillable Tax Form error F1040-524-01?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs, free-file-fillable-forms

The following is the error code sent back saying they were unable to process my return due to these error:

> "Business Rule F1040-524-01 - If 'PINTypeCd' in the Return Header has
>   the value "Self-Select On-Line" and Form 1040, Line 2 checkbox
>   "Married filing jointly" is not checked (element
>   'IndividualReturnFilingStatusCd' does not have the value 2), then
>   'PrimaryBirthDt' in the Return Header must match the e-File database."

The second statement reads:

> "The following information may help you determine the form at issue:
>   Field/Xpath:
>   /efile:Return/efile:ReturnHeader/efile:Filer[1]/efile:PrimarySSN"

I am not sure how to correct the "error".  I have checked filing "single" with 1 exemption.  My primary birthdate and SSN are correct.  Not sure what else to do.

Also in Section 2, line 4 my birthdate is also written correctly.  I refiled, but will probably get rejected again.  So confused.  Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a technical question about the e-file system

Comment: That error doesn't make sense to me given the info is correct, most common e-file issues are from a return already being filed for your SSN, or someone else claiming your dependent on a return. You may have to paper-file if IRS support is unable to help.

Comment: @DStanley Questions about filing taxes are on-topic here.

Comment: @DStanley: I disagree. I think this is [on topic](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as "Use of software for managing one's finances," especially as it's about filing directly with the government. I think there's a good reason for [tag:free-file-fillable-forms] questions and that they're on topic, as long as it's about how to use the tool itself (it's pretty finicky at times), much like questions about [tag:turbotax] or [tag:gnucash].

Answer (score 1):

Buried on the IRS web site is the "[Fillable Forms Error Search Tool](https://www.irs.gov/filing/individuals/free-file-fillable-forms)". Rather than including an explanation of errors in the rejection email itself, you're expected to copy and paste the error email into this form, which gives more details about what's wrong. (Don't blame me; I didn't design it.)

If I copy your error message in, here's the [response I get](https://www.irs.gov/filing/individuals/free-file-fillable-forms/free-file-fillable-form-codes/business-rule-f1040-524):

> ### Business Rule F1040-524-01
>
> #### Error:
>
> There is an error with the “primary taxpayer’s Date of Birth” in Step 2 Section 4.  The date of birth that was entered does not match IRS records.
>
> #### Solution:
>
> Make sure you enter the correct birth date, in the correct format, in the correct space.
>
> Scroll down, and enter the current date (“Today’s date”).  Today’s date is the day you intend to e-file the return again. Also, if you are making an electronic payment you must re-date that section.
>
> E-File your return.

You say that you've already checked your birthday, so I don't know as this is particularly helpful. If you're confident that it's correct and in the right place, I think your next step needs to be contacting the IRS directly. They have a link at the bottom of the error lookup response on how to [contact them specifically about their solution not working](https://www.irs.gov/uac/free-file-fillable-forms-solution-did-not-work), or you could try [contacting your local IRS office](https://www.irs.gov/help-resources/contact-your-local-irs-office) or [giving them a call](https://www.irs.gov/help-resources/telephone-assistance).